# There exists a continuous function which satisfies these properties?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

I am trying to solve this problem:

Find (if exists) a continuous function $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (or better a class of functions) such that
$$\lim_{|t|\to +\infty} h(t)=0,\quad 0<\liminf_{|t|\to +\infty}\, t h(t) <+\infty$$
and
$$ t h(t) \lesssim |t|^q$$
for some power $q>1$.

Could anyone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about $h(t)=\frac1  t$?

Comment: $\frac{t}{1+t^2}$. (Where does $p$ enter the problem?)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your comment. Do you think that, for $ \alpha\geq 1$ the class of functions given by $$\frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{1+ t^{\alpha}}$$ satisfies all the requirements?

Comment: @Chrystomath thank you for your comment. Do you think that, for $ \alpha\geq 1$ the class of functions given by $$\frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{1+ t^{\alpha}}$$ satisfies all the requirements?

Comment: @C.Bishop Only for $\alpha$ even. Otherwise $1+t^\alpha=0$ has a solution. For non-integer $\alpha$, and negative $t$, $t^\alpha$ is not real.

Comment: @Chrystomath clear, thank you. If you would write it as an answer I’ll accept it.

Comment: What is $p$? the question might miss some detail or you have added extra unecessary details.

Comment: @GAUSS1860 question edited, I missed to remove it, sorry.